# PHP Url Encode Remove all Encoded

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have the following code that im using to replace URL encode. I want to use str_replace() to replace anything %**

With * being wild characters.

I have the following code but want it to work how i said above.

```
    $desc = urlencode($desc);

    $desc = str_replace('%95', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%92', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%A3', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%91', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%92', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%27', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%09', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%0A', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%0D', '', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace('%2C', '', $desc);

    $desc = urldecode($desc); // remove +
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure % followed by two characters is an url escape sequence, you could use

```
$desc = preg_replace("@%.{2}@", '', $desc);
```

but a bit more precise would be

```
$desc = preg_replace("@%[\dA-F]{2}@", '', $desc);
```